# Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator < to types Function and Number

Tags: excel, powerquery

the error is :

> Expression.Error: We cannot apply operator < to types Function and Number.
>   Details: Operator=<    Left=[Function]   Right=16500

the code where the error gives :

```
#"Added Conditional Column4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom9", "Custom", List.Max( { 16500, each if [Gross Remuneration] > 200000 then 

     Number.From(if  [Gross Remuneration]*0.125 > 40000 then 40000 else [Gross Remuneration]*0.125) +  Number.From( if  [Gross Remuneration]*0.025 > 5000 then 5000 else [Gross Remuneration]*0.025 )

     else 

     Number.From(if [Gross Remuneration]*0.125 > 20000 then 20000 else [Gross Remuneration]*0.125) +  Number.From(if  [Gross Remuneration]*0.025 > 5000 then 5000 else [Gross Remuneration]*0.025)

     })


    )
```

i tried `Number.From` in front of the `each if` but didnt help me the find the maximum number between 16,500 and the number calculated after if clause.

thanks for the help.

Comment: i used two columns as a workaround... first column for the acf if part and second one for the maximum...

Comment: What does your data look like?

Answer (score 0):

You should move **each** keyword in front of List.Max.